# Filtering on nested JSON array: Rest Assured

Tags: json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to filter my GET response(JSON) based on a value in a nested JSON array. For eg: In the following JSON i want to filter an JSON array and print the names of cakes using Chocolate as batter.

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Choco Blueberry Cake",
"ppu": 0.55,
"batter":[
         { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
         { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
         { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" }
 ]
}
```

I have tried something like:

```
List<String> chocolateCakeList =jsonPath.getList("findAll{it.batter.type=='chocolate'}.name");
```

and

```
List<String> chocolateCakeList =jsonPath.getList("findAll{it.batter.it.type=='chocolate'}.name");
```

Both return empty Lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

1. First, if you want to use `findAll` then the object to be axtract must be an array. Your json is object {}, not an array []. Actually, your nested object `batter` is an array [].
2. keyword to search is `Chocolate`, not `chocolate`. Case-sensitive is applied here.

**Solution**

-If your whole response is exactly what you posted, then the path to extract is

```
String name = jsonPath.getString("name")
```

-If your response has structrure like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Choco Blueberry Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batter": [
      {
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
      },
      {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate"
      },
      {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Blueberry"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Choco Blueberry Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batter": [
      {
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
      },
      {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate 2"
      },
      {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Blueberry"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then the extraction is

```
List<String> list = jsonPath.getList("findAll {it.batter.findAll {it.type == 'Chocolate'}}.name");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . My response was an array as well. This solution worked.